# How does this pseudocode equal $\sum_{k = 0}^{\log_3{n} - 1} 3^k$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, discrete-mathematics, summation

We have this pseudocode

```
1 i = 1
2  while i < n
3   j = 0
4   while j ≤ i
5     j = j + 1
6   i = 3i
```

And they say that for sufficient large n, they have $$T(n) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\log_3{n} - 1} 3^k$$

Do you know how they got there ?

For $n=6$, both the sum and the code give the value 4. The value of $j$ in the code is $i + 1$ at the end, so if $i=3$ for example, $j$ will be $3+1=4$

For $n=9$ however, the sum gives $1+3+3^2=13$, but the code still gives $4$

Comment: Did you try it for some small n? If so include as sign of doing some work yourself.

Comment: I think the line `j = 0` is misplaced.  It should be above the first `while`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is clearly a mistake in the code

That said $\log_{b}(n)$ is defined as the solution or $b^x=n$, i.e you are looking for how many times you have to multiply $b$ with itself to get to $n$.

This pseudo-code does that when writing $i=3i$ in a while cycle. In particular you could sum over all successive powers to get the series, but this is not achieved by the given code.

Comment: So the code doesn't really equal $T(n)$ ? I wonder why they gave us that. It makes sense that $i = 3i$ and the condition $i < n$ implies $\log_3{n}$ because sooner or later, it will reach $n$ and get out of the loop

Comment: Exactly. Yet, it can be easily fixed to achieve the sum.